# Python: Plotting errorbars in a loglog scale, in a loop and then saving the image

Tags: python, plot, errorbar, loglog

I have 58 files that I need to plot. Some of them are empty (not important, I already skipped them with the if condition). I need to plot the data in the files, using a loglog scale, with error bars. And I want to save the plots in the end. 
I am using Python, spyder. 
I have written the following code:

```
route='/......./'
L=np.arange (1,59, 1)
for i in range (L.shape[0]):
    I=L[i]
    name_sq= 'Spectra_without_quiescent_'+('{}'.format(I))+'.dat' 
    Q=np.loadtxt(route+name_sq)
    if (len(Q) != 0):
        x=Q[:,1]
        y=Q[:,2]
        z=Q[:,3]
        fig=plt.errorbar(x,y,yerr=z, fmt = 'b')
        fig.set_yscale('log')
        fig.set_xscale('log')
        xlabel='Frequency'
        ylabel='Flux'
        title='Spectrum_'+('{}'.format(I))+'.dat'
        name='Spectrum_without_quiescent_'+('{}'.format(I))+'.pdf'
        fig.savefig(route+name, fig)
```

however, when I run it, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 540, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "/media/chidiac/My Passport/DOCUMENTS/My_Publications/2-3C273_radio_spectra/Maximum_flux_code.py", line 49, in <module>
    fig.set_yscale('log')
AttributeError: 'ErrorbarContainer' object has no attribute 'set_yscale'
```

I am still a beginner in Python and I couldn't find the error, or how to fix it. 
Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A friend of mine helped me with this issue and if someone is interested, here is the solution:

```
route='/....../'
L=np.arange (1,59, 1)
print L 
for i in range (L.shape[0]):
    I=L[i]
    name_sq= 'Spectra_without_quiescent_'+('{}'.format(I))+'.dat' 
    Q=np.loadtxt(route+name_sq)
    if (len(Q) != 0):
        x=np.log(Q[:,1])
        y=np.log(Q[:,2])
        z=np.log(Q[:,3])
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
    plt.errorbar(x,y,yerr=z, fmt = 'b')
    plt.ylabel('Flux', size='x-large')
    plt.xlabel('Frequency', size='x-large')
    title='Spectrum_'+('{}'.format(I))+'.dat'
    name='Spectrum_without_quiescent_'+('{}'.format(I))+'.pdf'
    pylab.savefig(route+name)
```

The first trick was, to first get the log values of the data and then plot them. Since I am not aware of any command that allows me to plot the errorbars in a logscale, I think this is the best solution. 
The second trick was to use subplots. Otherwise, I got the 58 curves in one plot, 58 times.

I hope this solution is helpful.

Comment: I suggest you mark the above answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 5):

This post may be a bit old, however I had the same problem and maybe this will help others in the future.

Your initial solution was actually almost correct. However, `set_yscale` is a method of the axes, not the figure. Thus your code in the if statement should look like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# other stuff you did ..

x=Q[:,1]
y=Q[:,2]
z=Q[:,3]
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes()
ax.set_xscale("log")
ax.set_yscale("log")
ax.errorbar(x,y,yerr=z, fmt = 'b')
ax.set_xlabel("Frequency")
ax.set_ylabel("Flux")
ax.set_title("Spectrum_{}.dat".format(I))
name="Spectrum_without_quiescent_{}.pdf".format(I)
plt.savefig(route+name)
```

Where I also adjusted your usage of the `format` function.

Note, that your **second solution will not always work** properly. If you have very small values and small errorbars the logarithm of these small values will get large (e.g. log(10^(-6)) = -6, as the logarithm to base 10 is used) and you will have huge errorbars though your actual error is small.

Long story short: Use `ax.set_*scale`. It's safe.